# Structural hashing of array of double in c#

Tags: c#, .net, hashcode

I would like to do structural hashing in a C# array, and I dont know how to do so.
This seems like a very basic and very simple question in any language, but I can't make it work in C#...

I have an array of 383 double. when I hash it, I get a very odd value

```
// this returns 134217728
let h = ((IStructuralEquatable) data).GetHashCode(EqualityComparer<double>.Default)
```

which happens to be such that `ln h / ln 2 = 27` ...

How can one get in C# the structural hashcode of an array of hashable stuff ?

**Edit** better illustration

In particular the following code would produce stupid results

```
    var vala = new[] { 1f, 354652f, 3f };
    var valb = new[] { 1f, 56f, 545013f };
    var valc = new[] { 1f, 2584356483f,  68763948475f };

    var hashA = ((IStructuralEquatable)vala).GetHashCode(EqualityComparer<float>.Default);
    var hashB = ((IStructuralEquatable)valb).GetHashCode(EqualityComparer<float>.Default);
    var hashC = ((IStructuralEquatable)valc).GetHashCode(EqualityComparer<float>.Default);
```

the hash is consistently `796917760`. (it seem to change with the 1st number though...)

**Conclusion**

The conclusion seems to be that structural hashing is just broken in C#, in practical terms.

(of course litterally, it is not, as others have argued an almost constant function is a valid hash function.....)

Comment: Hash-codes are *usually* very odd. What are you expecting? Besides: I think you'll agree `134217728` is actually even :)

Comment: Are you wanting a hash code for the entire contents of the array?

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, I'd like a hash code for the content of the array. so that I can compare it to another hashcode of another array.

Comment: @nicolas that is exactly what structural-equatable means; I've provided an example of it working fine. Can you show an example where it doesn't do what you intend? You are only showing you fetching one hash-code, which tells us... well, absolutely nothing. You need to compare 2 hash-codes to do anything useful.

Comment: It only works if you pass the EqualityComparer to GetHashCode(), and that's only available in .Net 4 or later.

Comment: Looks like the hash is based on the first item and the length of the array.  If your arrays are all the same length and especially if they tend to start with the same number then this is a bad hashing algorithm, in which case you'd want to write your own.

Comment: @juharr it looks like it is the case and is indeed a very bad hash. 'valid', but clearly lacking from the premises that leads you to use a hash in the first place. I ended up ditching C#.

Answer (score 3):

The value you get is not really odd because values returned by `GetHashCode` are **opaque**. You are not supposed to be able to derive *any* information from them, so any value is as odd as any other.

That said, `IStructuralEquatable` is billed as the solution to your problem, and indeed it works for me:

```
var a = new[] { 1f, 2f, 3f };
var b = new[] { 1f, 2f, 3f };

var hashA=((IStructuralEquatable)a).GetHashCode(EqualityComparer<float>.Default);
var hashB=((IStructuralEquatable)b).GetHashCode(EqualityComparer<float>.Default);

Console.WriteLine(hashA == hashB); // true
```

Comment: For info: [structural hashcode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.istructuralequatable.gethashcode.aspx) - basically, it would allow two collections to report as comparable if they contain the same items, for example

Comment: @nicolas what do you mean "not valid"? there is no such thing as an invalid hash-code. 2 hash-codes can be different, in which case they definitely represent different data - or they can be identical, in which case they *might* represent equal data, but we have to ask via `Equals` to find out... there is **absolutely nothing else** conveyed in a hashcode than that.

Comment: well that it does not perform a structural hash. that is what I am trying to do here. you know, the usual hash([1 2 3 ]) = hash([1 2 3 ])

Comment: @nicolas what have you compared it to? if a **different array (etc) instance** with the **same values** reports the same hash-code, then it is working fine. You can't say anything from just one object's hash-code; you need to compare 2

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks, that `IStructuralEquatable` cast was there and I didn't really see it. Hope I didn't do that on real code today :)

Comment: @MarcGravell well just looking at this one, I can tell you it does not perform what I intend it to...

Comment: @nicolas: It performs what *the designers* intended it to. If that's not good for you, (obviously) write something custom that is.

Comment: @Jon ok I take note of that. any idea about my question though ?

Comment: have you tried  var valc = new[] { 1f, 2f, 2f };var hashC = ((IStructuralEquatable)valc).GetHashCode(EqualityComparer<float>.Default);  ?

Comment: @nicolas: That's the exact same code as I give above, only with `c` instead of `a` and `b`. Which obviously doesn't make any difference.

Comment: just to be clear : your answer is not really working for a hash as it returns always the same value. not that it would prevent it to be upvoted..

Comment: @nicolas: You seem to have an incorrect understanding of what a hash is used for and what requirements there are for it. It *must* always return the same value, otherwise it would be useless.

Comment: Allow me to correct. what you want is a mapping from the input space to the output space. so, yes, this is a requirement to have the same output for the same input in the context of deterministic function, as taught in high school calculus. but you also want for a hash function to have its values spread out as uniformly as possible, to differentiate. of course, that fonction is not injective, but you want it to  be as injective as possible.

Comment: I realize you might still not have seen that valc is different. you guys are amazing.

Comment: @nicolas: Indeed, I still haven't seen the difference. Also, you might want to ask yourself if two of the top-ranked users on SO happened to be "amazing" in the very same manner on the very same subject, or perhaps if there is a more likely explanation.

Comment: @Jon it's ok I just told you 5 times it was different. take your time.  As for SO, it reminds me that a lot of people love PHP...

Comment: @nicolas: Obviously you are more interested in behaving immaturely than in learning whatever it is that prompted you to ask a question. I, on the other hand, am not interested in that. Have a good day.

Comment: @Jon Dude, all I am trying to get is an answer and you just continue to provide deluded misguidance even when I point you the obvious shortcoming of what you say. I ask a question on structural equality, and prof Marc explains me, nicely, what structural equality is after which you wrongly try to explain what hashing is....  go on, I am sure it provides value to some people who upvote your answers, but in that case, not so much.

Answer (score 1):

A structural hash-code indicates whether two different objects (or collections) represent *semantically* the same data. It is working fine; for example:

```
// invent some data
double[] vals1 = new double[383];
Random rand = new Random(12345);
for (int i = 0; i < vals1.Length; i++)
    vals1[i] = rand.NextDouble();
double[] vals2 = (double[])vals1.Clone();

// test with object rules
Console.WriteLine("{0} vs {1}",
    vals1.GetHashCode(), vals2.GetHashCode()); // 2 different numbers
Console.WriteLine(Equals(vals1, vals2)); // False

// now test using structural-equatable rules
IStructuralEquatable se1 = vals1, se2 = vals2;
var comparer = EqualityComparer<double>.Default;
Console.WriteLine("{0} vs {1}",
    se1.GetHashCode(comparer), se2.GetHashCode(comparer)); // 2 identical numbers
Console.WriteLine(se1.Equals(se2, comparer)); // True
```

Comment: So you are saying my code is correct (same than above) and 134217728 is a valid hash...

Comment: @nicolas exactly; `134217728` is a perfectly sensible hash. Until you compare it to another hash it means nothing (quite deliberately). Like I said before: if 2 hashes are different, they definitely represent different data; if 2 hashes are the same, you need to call `Equals` to find out whether they are *actually* the same.

Comment: Ok, so I should rephrase : how do I get a *good* hash, and not a crappy one ?

Comment: I mean, come on, you know the whole purpose of a hash is to not collide right ? and you can imagine that if I get 134217728 it is because the underlying hashing mechanism is inadequate for that purpose.

Comment: @nicolas the purpose of a hash is to allow quick comparison that is suitable for using in buckets etc, and ideally to *minimize* collisions. It is **impossible** to *never* collide for different values, unless your data has <= 32 bits of entropy (trivial to show). Why do you say that `134217728` is a crappy hash? that is a bizarre statement, unless it turns out that you get `134217728` for most different arrays. Again: what do you think is wrong with `134217728` ? Please state very clearly why you think that is a bad value. And please give an example of what you would consider a *good* value?

Comment: a value is not good or bad in and of itself, as you already have seen yourself. however, getting this specific value hints that the hasher is not doing its job, aka, that it is *bad* for the task at hand.

Comment: @nicolas in what way does it suggest that? sorry, but that is a non-sequitur. Please clarify why you think that, so that I can respond sensibly. What is the point you are trying to make about "this specific value" ?

Comment: @nicolas k; I feel like I'm banging my head against a wall: why do you think so? what is this prejudice against that value? what would be a good value? if you can't *please* answer that, I'm going to have to assume you're just trolling me...

Comment: of course that is just trolling. this is a perfectly fine value. and a hasher that always return 0 is *valid*. thank you

Comment: @nicolas well thanks for wasting my time then; yes a hash that always returns 0 is *valid*, but that *would* be an exceptionally poor hash. The one from your question: perfectly fine.

Comment: PS : the entropy part you are asserting is more of less correct as it is related to the minimum size of character encoding. but since you are a purist, the statement is incorrect (as I understand it). this minimum length limit is not guaranteed to the attained, and is only valid for an infinite amount of data.